# Typscript optional parameter in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a child component like so:

```
export const child= (iconPath?: string) => { /* return and all that good stuff here */ }
```

When rendering my component like so:

```
export const parent= () => { 
 return (
  <div>
   <child>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Im getting :

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.

What am I dooing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because React expects type for a component's first parameter (commonly known as `props`) to be an Object and it defaults to `{}`. You are trying to make it a `?string`, hence the complain.

You would generally define your Components with React.FC

```
export const child: React.FC<{iconPath?: string}> = (props) => {

  // iconPath will be available as props.iconPath
}
```

Now your parent component shouldn't complain

Comment: You should only be able to write jsx in a .tsx file, so yes

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just define the type of the props. Like so:

```
interface childProps {
  iconPath?: string
}
export const child= ({iconPath}: childProps) => { /* return and all that good stuff here */ }
```